# Apprequests from a Website

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

Is there any way to send apprequests if your application is a website?
I reported a bug on facebook http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182553325173000 but I do not know if this is possible or not

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this by adding the JS API,

before `<body>` add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function inviteFriends(){
         var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({
                method : 'apprequests',
                message: 'YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE',
         },
         function(receiverUserIds) {
                  console.log("IDS : " + receiverUserIds.request_ids);
                }
         );
    }
</script>
```

after the `<body>` include the API (asynchronous method):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
      oauth  : true  //enables OAuth 2.0
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

and call it:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="inviteFriends(); return false;"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:inviteFriends(); return false;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the Javascript SDK

it is in the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: But only from within a canvas app.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, as the other answers have shown, but the user will be brought to your canvas app when they accept the requests