# Send an apprequest withouth ssl

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I am using this to invite a friend of facebook to my app:

```
   function invite(id) {
        FB.ui({
          method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'mytext',
          title: 'mytitle',
          to: id, 
        }, function(response){
                if (typeof response.error_message != 'undefined') {
                    console.log(response.error_message);            
                }else{
                    if(response!=null){
                        var invitados = id.split(',');
                        for( i=0; i<invitados.length; i++){
                             $('#friend_'+invitados[i]).addClass('invited');

                        }
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

The problem is that I don't have ssl certificate in my server, yet (And I know this should be solved by installing it. Since facebook moved to secure login, we only need ssl to display our site in facebook's site)

And some users get a 501 error from facebook:

```
(net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE):
```

Is there a way to force opening the request (maybe in _blank) in my site instead of in facebook (inside the ifame)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to force opening the request (maybe in _blank) in my site instead of in facebook (inside the ifame)?

Nope.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/:

> User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Apprequests from a Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473739/apprequests-from-a-website).
You should be able to invoke invite request from your website. Though accepting a request will direct to the Canvas Page URL.

Answer (score 0):

In canvas apps you could try to set the "display" parameter to "page" or "popup":

```
FB.ui({
  display: 'page',
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'mytext',
  title: 'mytitle',
  to: id, 
}, callback)
```

The different display modes are documented at the bottom of this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: I will try that. But isn't it for the GUI of the user that invites (not for the one that recives the invitation)?

Comment: Yep, it's for the request dialog itself. Sorry, if I misunderstood your question. Sending the invited user anywhere else than the canvas app is not possible.